# Fastest way to convert sequence of bytes to string

Tags: java, string

What's the fastest way to convert a sequence of bytes to a Java String?

Specifically, given a large byte array, and a subsequence of bytes that correspond to ASCII characters, e.g.

```
byte[] bytes = { ... 65, 66, 67 ... };
```

and the start and end indexes of the subsequence, the desired output is the String "ABC".

Of course in the general case where the subsequence is the UTF-8 encoding of a Unicode string, it's more complex, but I'm writing a parser that 99.9% of the time will be dealing with ASCII, and needs to parse it as quickly as possible, so I'd like to implement fast-path code for that case.

Perhaps the most obvious way is:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(end - start);
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    stringBuilder.append((char) bytes[i]);
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

But I'm wondering is there a faster way?

Comment: You're going to have to explain why `new String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, Charset charset)` isn't fast enough for you.

Comment: There's a variety of `String` constructors with offsets and lengths and charsets. Look at the `String` javadoc.